# QGIS Interactive PDF Map - Pop Up Images

Tags: qgis, point, image, pdf, popup

I am a new user and still learning.

I created a map that when the user selects specific points on it, a pop-up image displays.

Is it possible to export this map as an interactive pdf and keep the pop-up image functionality?

Comment: How many points do you have in your point layer?